# Is it true: $||A||_2 = \min\{ ||A||_1 ,||A||_3,||A||_4,\ldots \ldots, ||A||_{\infty},\|A\|_F\} $?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

While running one algorithm , I observed the following peculiar relationship (at-least to me). I am not quite sure whether it is true in general, but I could not succeeded either in producing any counter example to nullify it.

Let $A$ be a square matrix;

$$\|A\|_2 \leq \|A\|_1\quad,$$

$$||A||_2 \leq ||A||_{\infty}\quad,$$

$$||A||_2 \leq ||A||_F\quad.$$

Where $||A||_1,||A||_2,||A||_{\infty}$ and $||A||_F$ are 1-norm, 2-norm, infinity norm and frobenius norm respectively.

Are above relationships indeed true? and if so, then is it correct to say that (2-norm) always lower bounds all the other norms. i-e $||A||_2 \leq ||A||_1 ,||A||_3,||A||_4,\ldots \ldots, ||A||_{\infty},||A||_F $ ?

Would be thankful for any suggestion.

Comment: Can't find a source at the moment, but I believe there is a theorem that states for $1 \leq p \leq q \leq \infty$, if $p < q$ then $||x||_q \leq ||x||_q$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: This question is asking about matrix norms, i.e. $||A||_p = \max_{||x||_p=1} ||Ax||_p$, which isn't the same as the vector norm of the components of $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All norms on a finite dimensional vector space are equivalent (that is, for any two norms A and B, there exist universal constants $C_1, C_2,C_3, C_4$ such that $C_1 || \cdot ||_A \leq || \cdot ||_B \leq C_2 || \cdot ||_A$ and  $C_3 || \cdot ||_B \leq || \cdot ||_A \leq C_4 || \cdot ||_B$).

But this by no means tells you one norm is always the smallest in a family of norms (without knowing the constants, anyway). A cute result from these [notes](http://www.pitt.edu/~hajlasz/Notatki/Functional%20Analysis2.pdf) related to Fritz John's ellipsoid theorem tells you on a n-dim real normed vector space with norm A, you can always find an inner product norm $B$ with $C_1 = 1$ and $C_2 = \sqrt{n}$ where these constants are indeed tight.

I just used Octave to generate some random matrices using the code:

octave:6> A=randn(2); norm(A)-norm(A,1)

ans =  0.023753

octave:7> A

A =

1.4542  -1.0416

-1.7263   2.0556

to get a counter example.

As for the other way around,

octave:15> A=randn(2); norm(A)-norm(A,1)

ans = -0.70221

octave:16> A

A =

0.30553  -1.79793

0.41323   0.93044

Comment: thanks for producing counter examples. My matrices were actually order > 50, and in that case it was very difficult to get norm(A)-norm(A,1)<0. :)